# Defining a list with label unindented and item indented

Tags: lists

I sat down tonight to try to define a simple list that looks something like this:

```
1:23
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

  Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
  aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
  imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
```

So you can see the requirements are fairly simple. The item label should not be indented at all, but should start precisely at the left margin. It should be followed by a line break. After the line break comes the item body. This shall be indented - the entire paragraph that is - and all following paragraphs by the same amount. However, there should be no paragraph commencing indent, all paragraphs should start on a blank line. In the example, the indentation is two spaces, but I think a quad would do nicely.

As possible complications, my document as a whole follows the above paragraphing style, with a blank line between paragraphs and no initial indentation. Secondly, I would like to format the item label in typewriter text.

So, clearly, I thought, I need a `list` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{}{}
  \item[1:23]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

  Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
  aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
  imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

But I got totally bamboozled trying to work out what to put as the second argument because the actual indentation of the label doesn't seem to be defined itself. Instead the `\leftmargin` is defined, with the item label shunted along relative to it by other relevant parameters which I couldn't decipher how to tweak.

Any additional explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look on the `enumitem` package, in my point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *do* want a list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,showframe} % showframe just for the example
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newenvironment{points}
 {\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=1em\labelwidth=\leftmargin\labelsep=0pt}%
  \newcommand{\point}[1]{\item[##1]\mbox{}\\*\ignorespaces}}
 {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{points}

\point{1:23}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

  Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
  aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
  imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.

\point{22:333}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

\end{points}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a really good answer! Is it possible to make the item labels typewriter text? (looks like it should be fairly easy, but I don't usually get as deep as needing two `##`s so I'm not too sure!

Comment: `\newcommand{\point}[1]{\item[\texttt{##1}]\mbox{}\\*\ignorespaces}`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be fairly close to what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlist{simple}{description}{1}
\setlist[simple]{leftmargin=4mm,   % indentation of paragraphs
                 font=\texttt,     % typewritter text for labels
                 style=nextline,   % start new line for "wide" labels
                 labelindent=0pt,  % the remaining settings make the
                 itemindent=-1.5mm,% width of the labels, with a small hack
                                   % to drag the label back to the margin
                 listparindent=0pt,
                 labelwidth=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{simple}
     \item[1:23]\lipsum[1-2]
     \item[1:24]\lipsum[1-2]
   \end{simple}

\end{document}
```

I have used [showframe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to show where the margins are. Note the small hack using `itemindent=-1.5mm` which for some reason is needed to get the label back to the margin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on using a `list` environment, and instead defined a new command using boxes. This works for me, but feels hack-y.

```
\newlength{\currentparskip}
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
\newcommand{\point}[2]{\texttt{#1} \\
  \makebox[1em]{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}%
    #2%
  \end{minipage}%
}
```

I found using a 1em wide box before the `minipage` necessary, because `\hfill` didn't seem to do anything.

It seems to do the job, though:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\currentparskip}
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
\newcommand{\point}[2]{\texttt{#1} \\
  \makebox[1em]{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}%
    #2%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\point{1:23}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

  Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
  aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
  imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
}

\point{1:24}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem.

  Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
  aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
  imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Mind you, I do get

```
Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--30
```

warnings.

Comment: I prefer the enumitem approach:)  Although, I notice that the `showframe` shows a small indentation of the labels Not sure why this happens.

Comment: @Andrew It has to be said, this produces erratically bad vertical spacing. In the end, I just relaxed my requirement for the item body to begin on the line below and went with `\newcommand{\tstamp}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\point}[2]{\tstamp{#1}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{1em}}%
    \item
    #2%
  \end{list}%
}` (sorry, I know that will look ugly in the comments). This allows me better control over the left margin and means the list item is not indented (or scarcely). One way or another, it ended up giving the output I most preferred anyway

Comment: @Andrew P.S. I've already upvoted and I'm very grateful for the help. I'm gonna leave the question officially unsolved though, if that's okay, because you didn't quite meet all the requirements and neither did I, and if anybody *can* I'd be very interested to see (and probably use) their efforts

Comment: I've just adjusted my solution to place the label on the margin. Have only just seen your comment about the bad vertical spacing.Not sure what to do about this, although nor can I reproduce it...

Comment: @Andrew Sorry I meant the bad vertical spacing was with my attempted solution, hence my decision to just tweak the requirements